# What wrong with my CSV creation code

Tags: ios, csv, email-attachments

I am trying to create a CSV file which then is email from the an iPad (the CSV file is also created on the iPad).

However my code does not work i think it is creating the CSV file and finding the file to send but the file is not being sent through email when i click send and retrieve the email but there is no file on the email.

Can any help me?

I am open to any questions.

Thanks
Alex

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSString *resultline=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@.%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,togS4.5%@,togS7.0%@,togS9.0%@,togS10.5%@,togS13.5%@,togS15.0%@,togD4.5%@,togD7.0%@,togD9.0%@,togD10.5%@,togD13.5%@,togD15.0%@,togK4.5%@,togK7.0%@,togK9.0%@,togK10.5%@,togK13.5%@,togK15.0%@,togSK4.5%@,togSK7.0%@,togSK9.0%@,togSK10.5%@,togSK13.5%@,togSK15.0%@,togE4.5%@,togE7.0%@,togE9.0%@,togE10.5%@,togE13.5%@,togE15.0%@,togA4.5%@,togA7.0%@,togA9.0%@,togA10.5%@,togA13.5%@,togA15.0%@,MIS%@\n",
                          self.custNameLabel4.text,
                          self.dateLabel4.text,
                          self.farbicLabel4.text,
                          self.fibreLabel4.text,
                          self.boundLabel4.text,
                          self.quantityLabel4.text,
                          self.sizeLabel4.text,
                          self.sasshlabel3.text,
                          self.innaLabel3.text,
                          self.packedLabel3.text,
                          self.outerLabel3.text,
                          self.palletLabel3.text,
                          self.weeksLabel2.text,
                          self.devileryLabel2.text,
                          self.customerLabel2.text,
                          self.DateLabel1.text,
                          self.textviewtext.text,
                          self.requested.text,
                          self.Elastic.text,
                          self.t1.text,
                          self.t2.text,
                          self.t3.text,
                          self.t4.text,
                          self.t5.text,
                          self.t6.text,
                          self.t7.text,
                          self.t8.text,
                          self.t9.text,
                          self.t10.text,
                          self.t11.text,
                          self.t12.text,
                          self.t13.text,
                          self.t14.text,
                          self.t15.text,
                          self.t16.text,
                          self.t17.text,
                          self.t18.text,
                          self.t19.text,
                          self.t20.text,
                          self.t21.text,
                          self.t22.text,
                          self.t23.text,
                          self.t24.text,
                          self.t25.text,
                          self.t26.text,
                          self.t27.text,
                          self.t28.text,
                          self.t29.text,
                          self.t30.text,
                          self.A1.text,
                          self.A2.text,
                          self.A3.text,
                          self.A4.text,
                          self.A5.text,
                          self.MIS.text];
    NSString *docPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    _textviewtext.text = resultline;
    NSString *topper=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/topper.csv"];

    [resultline writeToFile:topper atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    //NSLog(@"docpath saved");

    {MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate  = self;

        [picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email Address", nil]];
        [picker setSubject:self.custNameLabel4.text];
        [picker setMessageBody:@"Message"isHTML:NO];
        [picker addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"PathToFile.csv"]
                         mimeType:@"text/csv"
                         fileName:@"/topper.csv"];

        picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: So many issues:
**1)** You are not writing any data to file (//[fileHandle writeData:[resultline dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; code is commented)
**2)** You saved data to documentation directory but attaching from bundle ? ([picker addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"PathToFile.csv"]
                 mimeType:@"text/csv"
                 fileName:@"topper.csv"];)
**3)** NSString *file; never initialized but using it

Comment: There is no need to use a file. Simply get the `NSData` from the `NSString`. Writing a file and using the file's data for the attachment is pointless unless you really have a need to persist the CSV data as a file for later use.

Comment: What problems has your debugging turned up?

Comment: (That is, by the way, a terrible way to build `resultline` -- almost certain to contain an error, plus impossible to maintain.)

Comment: (Not to mention the fact that having that many individual labels is going to be buggy in and of itself.)

Comment: As @MidhunMP has pointed out, you've commented out the line that writes data to the file, so it's very unlikely you'll write anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are not writing to disk and passing full path of file for emailing.

Make sure you have included delegate MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
I have tested following code it works fine

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{


    NSString *resultline=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@.%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,togS4.5%@,togS7.0%@,togS9.0%@,togS10.5%@,togS13.5%@,togS15.0%@,togD4.5%@,togD7.0%@,togD9.0%@,togD10.5%@,togD13.5%@,togD15.0%@,togK4.5%@,togK7.0%@,togK9.0%@,togK10.5%@,togK13.5%@,togK15.0%@,togSK4.5%@,togSK7.0%@,togSK9.0%@,togSK10.5%@,togSK13.5%@,togSK15.0%@,togE4.5%@,togE7.0%@,togE9.0%@,togE10.5%@,togE13.5%@,togE15.0%@,togA4.5%@,togA7.0%@,togA9.0%@,togA10.5%@,togA13.5%@,togA15.0%@,MIS%@\n",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a",
                          @"a"];
    NSString *docPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *topper=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"topper.csv"];

    [resultline writeToFile:topper atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    //NSLog(@"docpath saved");




    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate  = self;

        [picker setSubject:@"abc"];
        [picker setMessageBody:@"Message"isHTML:NO];
        [picker addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:topper]
                         mimeType:@"text/csv"
                         fileName:@"topper.csv"];




    picker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;


    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];



}



-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Result: canceled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Result: saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Result: sent");

            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Result: failed");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Result: not sent");
            break;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shashi3456643 It's not emailing the file still I have edited the code from the ideas that have been put across.

Comment: I have updated my answer try this, I have tested code.

Comment: That code has work great, i now know where i have gone wrong. Thanks